# fill asp dropdown list with SQL records by using kentico API calls

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2017, kentico

okay, it seems that no one is explaining the process of this issue completely, even kentico's documentations are not well organized and clear. My problem is that i have more than 50 records in a table in SQL which i would like to load in a single ASP dropdown list (because it would be a bad practice to fill it statically), and I am new to kentico so my problem is that I need a complete explanation about the process from A to Z, from building the query in kentico, to using it in visual. please post some examples if possible.

also please note that i have seen many examples like this one:
https://docs.kentico.com/k10/custom-development/developing-web-parts/advanced-web-part-development-scenarios/developing-custom-filters

but these examples are showing us only the last step, which is using  DepartmentInfoProvider.GetDepartments(); to fill the dropdownlist, my main focus is to know how and where and using what they created the DepartmentInfoProvider class on the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was far more simple than I thought, First we should create a Query in Page Type --> Queries --> new Query --> specify queryName and queryText, the query gets the data from database, second in visual we have to write:

```
using System.Data;
 private void initializeDropDownList(String queryName, String rowName, DropDownList dd)
    {
        List<String> listData = new List<String>();
        DataSet dataset = new DataQuery("custom.PageType." + queryName).Execute();
        foreach (DataRow row in dataset.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            listData.Add(row[rowName].ToString());
        }
        String[] arrayData = listData.ToArray();
        foreach (String data in arrayData)
        {

            if (data.Equals("")) { continue; }
            else
            {
                dd.Items.Add(new ListItem(data));
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should read about [creating custom modules](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/custom-development/creating-custom-modules). There is a section how to add a class to the module. As soon as you add a class to the module, you'll be able to generate its Info and InfoProvider class, then add these files to solution and use them.

Answer (score 0):

Farah, Another person asked a similar question:

https://devnet.kentico.com/questions/custom-filter-with-a-drop-down-list-from-the-databse

This will help give a little info on the Info and InfoProviders in Kentico

To be more specific to your needs though, you can use the QueryInfoProvider.ExecuteQuery to use a [custom Kentico query](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/developing-websites/loading-and-displaying-data-on-websites/loading-data-using-custom-queries) that selects from your table, OR you can as Anton suggested make a custom module, but if you're new to Kentico this may be a bit much for you.

Lastly, if you want i have a universal filter webpart (just haven't published it yet) which gives you the ability to simply write a SQL query and then define how that selected value affects your repeater (you design the WHERE condition).  Just tell me if you want it.

Comment: thank you Trevor for your explanation, though I still have one missing part, I have created a query in the PageType that selects from SQL the wanted data, and then I added a Querydatasource to the Page that takes the query string from PageType query, and as I understood from your answer, the classes Info and InfoProvider are automatically generated by Kentico, now what is the next step after setting the queryDataSource in kentico? how to use it in visual? I mean what imports should I use? and what should be the class that executes the query?

Comment: Going the custom query way, you use the QueryInfoProvider.ExecuteQuery and pass the the page type code name and the query name (example "custom.mypagetype.myquery) and any parameters for it. This returns a data set that you can set your filter drop down to.

Comment: Thanks Trevor, now finally, can you provide me with some examples about this QueryInfoProvider.ExecuteQuery? since I couldnt find examples or any documentation under Kentico's documentation. this is the code that I am using and I am not getting any results, noting that the query is correct and it is returning data when testing it in the database:  QueryInfoProvider.ExecuteQuery("custom.LatestReleasesUpdated.GetSources", null, "","", -1, "", -1, -1, ref i  ); also please note that i is an int= 100

Comment: Sure!  Your example looks almost correct, i pass NULL in for the order by and where condition and columns, that signifies to use the defaults.  If your Custom.LatestReleasesUpdated.GetSources returns data normally, not having NULLs in those fields may be the only issue.


Try that, tell me if it doesn't work!


QueryInfoProvider.ExecuteQuery("custom.LatestReleasesUpdated‌​.GetSources", null, null,null, -1, null, -1, -1, ref i );